# Compiling Twilio C++ source

Tags: c++, windows-7, g++, twilio

I am new to C++, I am trying to compile the twilio library for it on Windows.

When I try to build the code I get the following error

To give a brief overview of what I have done and what I am using.

I have MinGW installed, all library files in the proper include folder under it.

I am using sublime for my IDE and this is the error received upon building it.

Update*

I have ran the make. I am copying the output from my Cygwin, but the normal DOS prompt gave the same output.

$ mingw32-make

ar rcs twilio-cplusplus.a Rest.o TwiML.o Utils.o

I can copy the make file or any of the code here if that would help just let me know and thank you for the responses thus far.

end update*

I know I must be missing something simple and any help will be appreciated.

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccInjOWV.o:Examples.cpp:(.text+0x313): undefined reference to `twilio::Rest::request(std::string const&, std::string const&, std::vector<twilio::Var, std::allocator<twilio::Var> > const&)'
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccInjOWV.o:Examples.cpp:(.text+0x74a): undefined reference to `twilio::Rest::request(std::string const&, std::string const&, std::vector<twilio::Var, std::allocator<twilio::Var> > const&)'
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccInjOWV.o:Examples.cpp:(.text+0xb69): undefined reference to `twilio::Rest::request(std::string const&, std::string const&, std::vector<twilio::Var, std::allocator<twilio::Var> > const&)'
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccInjOWV.o:Examples.cpp:(.text+0xc74): undefined reference to `twilio::Say::setLoop(int)'
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccInjOWV.o:Examples.cpp:(.text+0xcae): undefined reference to `twilio::Say::setVoice(std::string const&)'
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccInjOWV.o:Examples.cpp:(.text+0xcdc): undefined reference to `twilio::Verb::append(twilio::Verb&)'
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccInjOWV.o:Examples.cpp:(.text+0xcf1): undefined reference to `twilio::Verb::toXML()'
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccInjOWV.o:Examples.cpp:(.text+0xd54): undefined reference to `twilio::Gather::setNumDigits(int)'
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccInjOWV.o:Examples.cpp:(.text+0xdca): undefined reference to `twilio::Verb::append(twilio::Verb&)'
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccInjOWV.o:Examples.cpp:(.text+0xde2): undefined reference to `twilio::Verb::append(twilio::Verb&)'
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccInjOWV.o:Examples.cpp:(.text+0xdfa): undefined reference to `twilio::Verb::append(twilio::Verb&)'
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccInjOWV.o:Examples.cpp:(.text+0xe0f): undefined reference to `twilio::Verb::toXML()'
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccInjOWV.o:Examples.cpp:(.text+0xfe3): undefined reference to `twilio::Utils::validateRequest(std::string const&, std::string const&, std::vector<twilio::Var, std::allocator<twilio::Var> >&)'
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccInjOWV.o:Examples.cpp:(.text$_ZN6twilio3SayC1ERKSs[twilio::Say::Say(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)]+0x14): undefined reference to `twilio::Verb::V_SAY'
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccInjOWV.o:Examples.cpp:(.text$_ZN6twilio6GatherC1Ev[twilio::Gather::Gather()]+0x3a): undefined reference to `twilio::Verb::V_GATHER'
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccInjOWV.o:Examples.cpp:(.text$_ZN6twilio6GatherC1Ev[twilio::Gather::Gather()]+0x66): undefined reference to `twilio::Verb::V_SAY'
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccInjOWV.o:Examples.cpp:(.text$_ZN6twilio6GatherC1Ev[twilio::Gather::Gather()]+0x7c): undefined reference to `twilio::Verb::V_PLAY'
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccInjOWV.o:Examples.cpp:(.text$_ZN6twilio6GatherC1Ev[twilio::Gather::Gather()]+0x92): undefined reference to `twilio::Verb::V_PAUSE'
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccInjOWV.o:Examples.cpp:(.text$_ZN6twilio8RedirectC1Ev[twilio::Redirect::Redirect()]+0x3a): undefined reference to `twilio::Verb::V_REDIRECT'
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccInjOWV.o:Examples.cpp:(.text$_ZN6twilio13TwiMLResponseC1Ev[twilio::TwiMLResponse::TwiMLResponse()]+0x3a): undefined reference to `twilio::Verb::V_RESPONSE'
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccInjOWV.o:Examples.cpp:(.text$_ZN6twilio13TwiMLResponseC1Ev[twilio::TwiMLResponse::TwiMLResponse()]+0x66): undefined reference to `twilio::Verb::V_GATHER'
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccInjOWV.o:Examples.cpp:(.text$_ZN6twilio13TwiMLResponseC1Ev[twilio::TwiMLResponse::TwiMLResponse()]+0x7c): undefined reference to `twilio::Verb::V_RECORD'
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccInjOWV.o:Examples.cpp:(.text$_ZN6twilio13TwiMLResponseC1Ev[twilio::TwiMLResponse::TwiMLResponse()]+0x92): undefined reference to `twilio::Verb::V_DIAL'
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccInjOWV.o:Examples.cpp:(.text$_ZN6twilio13TwiMLResponseC1Ev[twilio::TwiMLResponse::TwiMLResponse()[Finished in 3.9s with exit code 1]]+0xa8): undefined reference to `twilio::Verb::V_SAY'
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccInjOWV.o:Examples.cpp:(.text$_ZN6twilio13TwiMLResponseC1Ev[twilio::TwiMLResponse::TwiMLResponse()]+0xbe): undefined reference to `twilio::Verb::V_PLAY'
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccInjOWV.o:Examples.cpp:(.text$_ZN6twilio13TwiMLResponseC1Ev[twilio::TwiMLResponse::TwiMLResponse()]+0xd4): undefined reference to `twilio::Verb::V_REDIRECT'
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccInjOWV.o:Examples.cpp:(.text$_ZN6twilio13TwiMLResponseC1Ev[twilio::TwiMLResponse::TwiMLResponse()]+0xea): undefined reference to `twilio::Verb::V_REJECT'
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccInjOWV.o:Examples.cpp:(.text$_ZN6twilio13TwiMLResponseC1Ev[twilio::TwiMLResponse::TwiMLResponse()]+0x100): undefined reference to `twilio::Verb::V_HANGUP'
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccInjOWV.o:Examples.cpp:(.text$_ZN6twilio13TwiMLResponseC1Ev[twilio::TwiMLResponse::TwiMLResponse()]+0x116): undefined reference to `twilio::Verb::V_PAUSE'
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccInjOWV.o:Examples.cpp:(.text$_ZN6twilio13TwiMLResponseC1Ev[twilio::TwiMLResponse::TwiMLResponse()]+0x12c): undefined reference to `twilio::Verb::V_SMS'
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: You probably haven't add library to your linker rules, have you?

Comment: This issue is def a linking problem.  Are you using the Makefile?

Comment: I think this may have been my mistake, I did not use the link file.